# How to split wordpress the_content in 3 columns without using <--more-->

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to Split wordpress Bydefault content in 3 columns through wordcount not by letter count. what is the exact code for this. Here is my code html---

```
<p>Chandigarh and its surrounding provinces were hit by rain early morning. The Punjab and Haryana authorities were kept on a high alert due to the storm advisory sent by the Met department. The weather bureau in Delhi has been informed of the thunderstorms, gusty winds, and squalls. These are likely to affect many regions of the country including Delhi, till Friday. This is quite prevalent as the mountains of Himachal Pradesh received an unsmoked snowfall. </p>
<p>On Monday the weather warning bulletin, India Meteorological Department said that some states including Bihar, Uttar Pradesh, West Bengal, Odisha, Karnataka, Kerala, and Sikkim are more likely to be a prey to gusty winds and thunderstorm. The weather officer recorded his statements that say “Thunderstorms and squalls are “very, very likely at isolated places in Haryana, Chandigarh, and Delhi”. The weather bulletin displayed warning due to the heat wave conditions in the two pockets in Vidarbha, Maharashtra. The weather bureau in Delhi has been informed of the thunderstorms, gusty winds, and squalls. </p>

<section>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="left">
                <h4 class="heading4">Highlights:</h4>
                <ul class="ul-highlights">
                    <?php while( have_rows('high_lights') ): the_row();?>
                        <li><?php the_sub_field('highlight');?></li><?php endwhile;?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="right">
                <p>Chandigarh and its surrounding provinces were hit by rain early morning. The Punjab and Haryana authorities were kept on a high alert due to the storm advisory sent by the Met department. The weather bureau in Delhi has been informed of the thunderstorms, gusty winds, and squalls. These are likely to affect many regions of the country including Delhi, till Friday. This is quite prevalent as the mountains of Himachal Pradesh received an unsmoked snowfall. </p>
                <p>On Monday the weather warning bulletin, India Meteorological Department said that some states including Bihar, Uttar Pradesh, West Bengal, Odisha, Karnataka, Kerala, and Sikkim are more likely to be a prey to gusty winds and thunderstorm. The weather officer recorded his statements that say “Thunderstorms and squalls are “very, very likely at isolated places in Haryana, Chandigarh, and Delhi”. The weather bulletin displayed warning due to the heat wave conditions in the two pockets in Vidarbha, Maharashtra. The weather bureau in Delhi has been informed of the thunderstorms, gusty winds, and squalls.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<p>Chandigarh and its surrounding provinces were hit by rain early morning. The Punjab and Haryana authorities were kept on a high alert due to the storm advisory sent by the Met department. The weather bureau in Delhi has been informed of the thunderstorms, gusty winds, and squalls. These are likely to affect many regions of the country including Delhi, till Friday. This is quite prevalent as the mountains of Himachal Pradesh received an unsmoked snowfall. </p>
<p>On Monday the weather warning bulletin, India Meteorological Department said that some states including Bihar, Uttar Pradesh, West Bengal, Odisha, Karnataka, Kerala, and Sikkim are more likely to be a prey to gusty winds and thunderstorm. The weather officer recorded his statements that say “Thunderstorms and squalls are “very, very likely at isolated places in Haryana, Chandigarh, and Delhi”. The weather bulletin displayed warning due to the heat wave conditions in the two pockets in Vidarbha, Maharashtra. The weather bureau in Delhi has been informed of the thunderstorms, gusty winds, and squalls.</p>
```

Comment: you mean you need to replace in place of `<p>` tags

Comment: I don't see `the_content()` anywhere?

Comment: where is your the_content()

Comment: anyway - when ever you want to permently change the strutcture (add or substract something) you use this hook/filter : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/

Comment: <p>Chandigarh and its surrounding provinces were hit by rain early morning. The Punjab and Haryana authorities were kept on a high alert due to the storm advisory sent by the Met department. The weather bureau in Delhi has been informed of the thunderstorms, gusty winds, and squalls. These are likely to affect many regions of the country including Delhi, till Friday. This is quite prevalent as the mountains of Himachal Pradesh received an unsmoked snowfall. </p>
 -Supose this is my "the_content". i want to split this in three part and can using it in diff. place without using <--more-->.

Comment: Extra `<div>` (ending) removed

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$word = "Hello this a sample content";
$word_count = str_word_count($word);

$breakpoint=$word_count /3;

$substring1 = substr($word,0,$breakpoint);
$substring2 = substr($word,$breakpoint,$breakpoint*2);
$substring3 = substr($word,$breakpoint*2); 
?>
```

Now you have 3 substrings to be printed in 3 different places.